# Altering table to add column before specific column

Tags: mysql, alter

Say I have this structure:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | created | createdby
```

I want to add a column after `col4`, but there are a few problems. There could be any number of 'Col' columns, so using `AFTER` isn't an option (Ill never know *what* it comes after). So, naturally, I though I can just do `BEFORE created`, right? Well this doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD extracol VARCHAR(255) BEFORE created
```

Is there a way to get this working? I just get an invalid syntax error. I would have though if I can add a column `AFTER` a specific column, then I can do it `BEFORE` but apparently that's not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that

If you really want them in that specific order you will  have to create a new table with the columns in that order and copy the existing data Or rename columns

There is no easy way

Comment: i tried this some months back in sql server for my very `own` project i couldn't fine a solution !!

Comment: Really? This seems like it would be such a common problem. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Harry's solution does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but it takes two queries and little 'out of the box' thinking:

First insert the new column *after* the column we really want it before:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table ADD extracol VARCHAR(255) AFTER created
```

Then use another alter command to move the previous column after the new one. You'll need the right column type for the other column here:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY created DATETIME AFTER extracol
```

*Untested. Backup all your data before testing or running.*

Comment: Awesome, love it!

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnname INT AFTER anothercolumn

the above syntax is valid in MySQL but is not valid in SQL Server.